# React Axios Get Call to Output JSON Format

Tags: arrays, reactjs, d3.js, axios

I am performing an Axios get call in a React Component to retrieve JSON info. That function is working great. Within the JSON is a label for various network ports, which are returning as an array in my axios call. These are ultimately going to be displayed as nodes on a d3 graph. My issue is that I need to output the data pulled from the get call into the following format:

```
nodes: [
    { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
    { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
    { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
    { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
    { id: 'JSON data.label here' }
]
```

So the full component for the graph to read is:

```
export const data = {
    nodes: [
        { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
        { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
        { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
        { id: 'JSON data.label here' },
        { id: 'JSON data.label here' }
    ]
}
```

Here is the format of the Axios get I am using:

```
axios.get(`NetworkConstruct.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const names = res.data.items;
        this.setState({ names });            
       });
```

Here is a sample output I am receiving (there are 11 of these):

```
{id: "5bc0860c-ece1-461c-bac0-b155a3cacd82", label: "80.107.0.212",  
resourceTypeId: "tosca.resourceTypes.NetworkConstruct", productId: 
"5bc0835c-6cfa-486e-8429-a59eaf4118bc", tenantId: "393fa8da-61fd-458c-80f9- 
ce92d0ef0330", …}
```

The data has to be in this EXACT format or the graph won't read it. I'm guessing I'll need to do an initial map function but am stuck on how to arrange it. I cannot have any divs or quotes in my output. Is this doable? I have scoured the boards and Google for a couple of days and can't make this work yet.

Here is the object I am receiving from the GET request.

```
{
    "id": "5bd2c6ef-6009-4b90-9156-62168f3c6293",
    "resourceId": "5bd0ba82-2994-455d-8716-2adb5694d6f0",
    "interface": "getGraph",
    "inputs": {},
    "outputs": {
       "graph": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "5bcdf06c-dd53-4335-840f-55a4b8d85a2d",
                "name": "asw-lab9306b",
                "ports": {
                    "GigabitEthernet3/0/8": "5bd1777f-0ab9-4552-962b-9e306ce378ab",
                    "GigabitEthernet2/0/15": "5bd1777e-119c-44e8-ba69-0d86a481c0f5",
                    "GigabitEthernet3/0/47": "5bd17783-be94-4aaf-8858-70e4eb3d02dc",
                    "GigabitEthernet2/0/13": "5bd17783-ed99-453f-a958-f764edaa8da8"
                }                                
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "a": "5bd1a467-13f2-4294-a768-561187b278a8",
                "z": "5bd17770-2e6c-4c37-93c8-44e3eb3db6dd",
                "layer": "ETHERNET"
            },                
            {
                "a": "5bd1776e-c110-4086-87d6-a374ccee419a",
                "z": "5bd17770-83ee-4e10-b5bb-19814f9f5dad",
                "layer": "ETHERNET"
            }
        ]
    }
},
    "state": "successful",
    "reason": "",
    "progress": [],
    "providerData": {},
    "createdAt": "2018-10-26T07:49:03.484Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-26T07:49:25.425Z",
    "resourceStateConstraints": {},
    "executionGroup": "lifecycle"
}
```

The info I need is the nodes ID. There are eleven of them in the full object.

Comment: How does the original format look like that you get in the response? Can you add an example?

Comment: Sure, here is the format of the return array in console.log. i've got 11 of these returns:  {id: "5bc0860c-ece1-461c-bac0-b155a3cacd82", label: "80.107.0.212", resourceTypeId: "tosca.resourceTypes.NetworkConstruct", productId: "5bc0835c-6cfa-486e-8429-a59eaf4118bc", tenantId: "393fa8da-61fd-458c-80f9-ce92d0ef0330", …}

Comment: If you don't show us the initial format of what you have it's hard to help. The format that you want as the result of your operations is perfectly doable. Could you show us some data examples, and also show us the `get` function where you return the data? This format could be returned from that `get` function as well.

Comment: @CHays412 Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52987842/edit) function to add the example to your original question. Do not post it as a comment.

Comment: Edited my post. Sorry about the comments I'm pretty new to the site.

Comment: @CHays412 you say that you are receiving 11 of those... are they contained in an array? what type is `names `, is it an array?

Comment: @CHays412 so if I understand correctly, you want to get the value of `label` and replace the value of `id`, and remove every other property of each of the objects inside the array? Have you already tried the answer from trixn and any of his edits?

Answer (score 0):

You can map an array of objects to another array of objects in your format with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Assuming that `data` is the list of objects from your response:

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
    state = {
        nodes: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('the url').then(response => {
            const nodes = response.data.outputs.graph.nodes;
            this.setState({nodes});
        });
     }

    render() {
        const {nodes} = this.state;

        if (!nodes) return 'Loading...'

        return <TheD3ComponentYouUse nodes={nodes} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an "response.data.map is not a function" error.

Comment: @CHays412 Updated my answer, please try it this way.

Comment: Thank you, trixin. I'm still getting the same error. In course of trying to do this I've realized that the response I am getting is an object instead of an array, which is why I am getting errors. So I'm wondering if I should try to transform it to an array or just deal with parsing the object.

Comment: @CHays412 That depends on what you need from the response. If you add an example of the full response object I can help you to extract and transform the data you need.

Comment: Will get that posted ASAP. Thank you so much!

Comment: Edited my initial query with the object I am receiving from get call.

Comment: @CHays412 Okay so why aren't you just accessing `request.data.outputs.graph.nodes` then? It seems to already have the structure you want?

Comment: I think it is working. Thank you so much for your help.